# Why won't/How can sort PHP session variables not unsetting

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

It would seem that with all my attempts, session variables are not being unset when being instructed to. The methods I have tried are:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['name']);
$_SESSION = array();
```

and all combined. I have verified with var_dump that the variable itself still holds the value. I have tried using headers to disable browser caching:

```
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

(and all of the above combined) but as far as I can see that's not even the problem.
The only thing that unsets the variable is closing the browser. I understand session UIDs are stored in a special? cookie but have no idea how to manipulate/delete this directly and am not even sure if that's the solution (although the only idea I have).

Full code..

Index.htm:

```
<html>
<?php
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
?>

<a href = "new_user.htm"> New User</a><br>
<a href = "Login.htm"> User Login</a><br>
<a href = "search.htm"> Search</a><br>
<a href = "member.php"> Member</a><br>

</html>
```

Logout.htm (whereby session vars are unsest etc):

```
<html>

<?php
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

session_start();

unset($_SESSION['name']);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();

?>
Logout Succesful.<br><br>
<a href = "index.htm">index</a>

</html>
```

member.php (where the session var is dumped):

```
<?php
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{

$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.htm");
//echo $_SESSION['user'];
}

?>

<html>
<body>

<?php 
$uu = $_SESSION['user'];
var_dump($uu);
?>

Main User Page.++Code++
(seperate pages atm for ease+speed of writing,<br>
embedded stuff would take a bit longer)<br><br>
<a href = "addservice.php"> Add Service </a><br>
<a href = "additem.php"> Add Item </a><br>
<a href = "search.htm"> Search </a><br><br>
<a href = "logout.htm"> Logout </a><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Login.php:

```
<html>

<?php

$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test_db";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,"",$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>

<form action="log_in.php" method="post">
UserName: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>

<input type="submit"><br>
</form>

<?php

?>

</html>
```

which leads to log_in.php(where the session variables are set):

```
<?php
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test_db";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,"",$database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$username_l = $_POST['username'];
$pword_l = $_POST['password'];

$q_usercheck = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE User_Name='$username_l'";
$q_pwcheck = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE User_Name = '$username_l' and Password = '$pword_l'";

$uc_result = mysqli_query($con, $q_usercheck);
$uc_count = mysqli_num_rows($uc_result);

$pc_result = mysqli_query($con, $q_pwcheck);
$pc_count = mysqli_num_rows($pc_result);

if ($uc_count != 1)
{
echo "<br>invalid username<br>";
     var_dump($uc_result);
}

if ($uc_count == 1)
{

 if ($pc_count == 1)
            {
              //echo "Login Successful +code";
              session_start();                
              $_SESSION[user] = $username_l;
              header("location:member.php");
            }

    }              

else
{
    echo "<br>Invalid password for username + code<br>";
     var_dump($username_l);

    }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
<br>
<a href = "index.htm">index</a>;
```

Comment: Browser caching has nothing to do with session variables, they're on the server.

Comment: Provide the whole code that both `unset`s a variable and then `var_dump`s it

Comment: All the things at the top should work. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: session_destroy is enough to destroy whole session. There might be something else causing problem. It better if you share complete code and outputs

Comment: Ok, I have added all the code from the various related scripts..

Comment: Why is your logout page called `logout.htm` rather than `logout.php`? Is the PHP code actually being processed in that page, or is it just being output to the browser as-is (check View Source)?

Comment: It looks as if it is being sent to browser as is.. (can see the <php? tags in the view source etc).. is this not supposed to happen?

Comment: Ok it seems renaming .php has solved the problem! So I see you need to contain pages containing php .php.. lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing

```
session_start();
```

Add it to your code and try something like this (in this order):

```
session_start(); 
unset($_SESSION['name']); 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();
```

To clear all your session variables, this works for me all the time:

```
session_start ();
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```